# Spring Framework: How to access different databases from JDBCTemplate based on web domain that the user enters in the browser?

Tags: java, spring, database, multi-tenant, jdbctemplate

I am use Spring MVC to build web. Now I have many customers. I want customer 1 (domain: [www.cus1.com](http://www.cus1.com)) access database `cus1`, customer 2 (domain: [www.cus2.com](http://www.cus2.com)) access database `cus2`... How to do that? I use JDBCTemplate in Spring. Do we have any solution or libraries for this case?

Comment: are you going to have separate deployments for each customers? If so... use properties file to specify the datasource that a deployment needs. As long as your queries are DB independent you will be good.

Comment: If you want to tie customer to a subdomain and have a single deployable , then configure multiple DataSource beans and find a way to map the subdomain extracted from request to the DataSource bean.

Comment: Hi @gtiwari333 I don't separate deployments for each customers.  Only 1 server and 1 source but can access by many domain. Thanks

Comment: These two articles might be useful. https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/ https://www.schakko.de/2020/06/04/handling-subdomains-in-multi-tenant-applications-with-spring-boot-web-mvc/